# nestedSortable -> Uncaught TypeError: $.ui.isOverAxis is not a function

Tags: jquery, nested-sortable

Trying to implement nestedSortable (https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable) in my system.

Using lastest stable jquery and jquery-ui, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ui.isOverAxis is not a function
```

Looking into jquery-ui.js

```
$.ui.intersect = (function() {
    function isOverAxis( x, reference, size ) {
        return ( x >= reference ) && ( x < ( reference + size ) );
    }

    return function( draggable, droppable, toleranceMode, event ) {
```

I found the above.. so it exists..

any one have a clue?

> Edit: Even tried to change jquery /-ui to 1.10.1 and 1.10.2 (saw sortable and draggable in jsfiddle work with those versions..)

Answer (score 0):

aaand a great friend of mine (alexandar) fixed it.

```
var ns = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    maxLevels: 4,
    //isTree: true,
    expandOnHover: 700,
    startCollapsed: false,
    change: function(){
     console.log('Relocated item');
    }
   });
```

remove the isTree parameter. Seems it must be experimental ;-)